# How to know if the viewport width is greater than its height using a mediaquery

Tags: css, media-queries

is there a way to perform this operation in css ?
`@media screen and (min-width < min-height)`

I started writting a front-end library and I want "responsive" based on this condition.

Comment: what's the specific purpose? could you make a practical example of what do you want to achieve?

Comment: For example I want a fixed top horizontal menu if height > width and a fixed vertical menu if width >= height.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check for the orientation

```
@media all and (orientation: landscape) {
  body:after {
     content: "width is greater than height"
  }
}

@media all and (orientation: portrait) {
  body:after {
     content: "height is greater than width"
  }
}
```

Comment: Also min-width: 100vh